# Can I force the MVC-6-Grid to understand the data annotation on the fields

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, webgrid

I have added the following model class inside my asp.net MVC core web application 3.1:-

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(Submission_Validation))]
    public partial class Submission
    {


    }
```

and the following `Submission_Validation` class:-

```
public class Submission_Validation
    {

[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

now if i show the `Created` field using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Created)` the date will have the correct format as specified inside the data annotation, but if i render the value inside the MVC-6-Grid ( https://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/) as follow:-

```
@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
columns.Add(model => model.Created).Titled("Created")
})
    .Using(GridFilterMode.Header)
    .Empty("No data found")
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pager =>
    {

        pager.RowsPerPage = 250;
    })
```

the date will ignore the data annotation specified. any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format it in the Grid:

```
columns.Add(model => model.Created).Titled("Created").Formatted("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}");
```